# How to use ngModel in ion-checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to use  with ngModel, but ngModel doesn't work there.
My code:

```
<ion-checkbox *ngFor="#item of items" [(ngModel)]="item.checked">
  {{item.name}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

But I get an error:

> EXCEPTION: Expression 'checked in AddInterestItem@5:2' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'false' in [checked in AddInterestItem@5:2]

example data:

```
this.items = [ 
  {name: 'Dancing', checked: false}, 
  {name: 'Jazz', checked: false}, 
  {name: 'Metal', checked: true}, 
  {name: 'Pop', checked: false}, 
  {name: 'Rock\'n\'Roll', checked: false}, 
  {name: 'Folk Metal', checked: true} 
];
```

Comment: This error message is not related to `ngModel` but to `="item.checked". You seem to change `item.checked` in a way that is not compatible with Angulars default change detection. Please provide more details about how this looks in your code.

Comment: Seems you are changing the values in some unexpected way. This is still not enough information.

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with `<ion-checkbox>`.
But when i tried to repeat your story with normal 
`<input type="checkbox" />`,
I couldn't get success by applying ngFor to `input type="checkbox"` directly.
So what I did, I took `<ul><li *ngFor="#item of items" >` and put my `input type="checkbox"` within it and it started working as expected.

I feel like [MyAnswer](http://plnkr.co/edit/x9O4VPwXRQWdZQFixzJu?p=preview) could help you further.

**doesn't work in mycase**

```
<input  type="checkbox" *ngFor="#item of items" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" />{{item.name}}  
/* I don't know some error occurs. you can check my plunkr by modifying it/*.
```

**Worked properly**

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#item of items">{{item.name}}
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes I think thats the right way you should use ng-for.  In the nightly build from Ionic about checkboxes, they Are wrapping it into a container too +1

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick update for Ionic 4:

HTML:

```
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="iLikeIt.isChecked"></ion-checkbox>
```

Ts:

```
iLikeIt={isChecked:false}
```