# Issues with setting ion-checkbox value using arrays in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have been trying to figure out the best way to set a series of `ion-checkbox`'s using an array that is fed into my app through an API.

Right now, my app receives some data that looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "tags": [
            55, 46, 193, 1002
        ]
    }
}
```

I am then using a series of `ion-checkbox`'s to display whether or not that tag is selected for a certain item, like this:

```
<ion-item lines="full">
   <ion-label position="fixed" class="ion-text-wrap">Blue</ion-label>
   <ion-checkbox slot="end" [(ngModel)]="item.tags" [value]="55" [checked]="item.tags.indexOf(55) > 0"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

I am getting an error with the `indexOf` function, saying it's not a function.

Is there a better way to try and create a list of items and see if the value is in an array, and then show the checkbox as checked if it is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ngModel in ion-checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917712/how-to-use-ngmodel-in-ion-checkbox)

Comment: Should also post your compoonent code. Also should spend a minute in a search engine researching your question.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=array+indexOf. It says not a function because you aren't using it properly. There's also a very similar question here on SO that should get you going in right direciton. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917712/how-to-use-ngmodel-in-ion-checkbox